# Is it possible to use factory_girl.js with teaspoon?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript, teaspoon

As part of my trying to learn web development, I have reached a point were I have some coffeescript classes I would like to test inside my rails environment.

I have a rails 4.03 app that I have been working on (it is based off the rails [tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/)).
During the process of learning rails, I got used to working with rspec and FactoryGirl, so I would like to try to follow a similar flow for the coffeescript if possible.

I wrote all my coffeescript as individual classes, each in there own file, so I think they should be testable.

I currently have [teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon) installed, which looks a lot like rspec. I have this working with some basic tests, but now I need to start writing real tests.  Teaspoon has support for fixtures, but I noticed that there is a node.js package called [factory_girl](https://www.npmjs.org/package/factory_girl),  which seems like it is a port of the ruby FactoryGirl for rspec. I installed this package using npm -install and now I have it listed in my rails folder under "node_modules".

Can someone tell me if it is possible to use this package to generate objects for testing with teaspoon, and if so how?

**Update:**
I am marking the answer below as accepted, because I was able to get FactoryGirl to run.
What I did was (as suggested in the answer) was to copy the factory_girl.js file into a location that could be loaded by the assets pipeline spec/javascripts/support, and then required it in the spec/javascripts/spec_helper.coffee file.

The problem is that the functionality does not seem to match what happens in rails (unless I am completely forgetting how it worked in rails).  In Rails, I could define a factory for a model and the objects created would be instances of the class I was associating the factory with.  Here there does not seem to be any association with the class I am trying to generated instances of.  For example, only the properties I define in the factory definition are available, and none of the methods are defined on the objects.
I could be doing something completely wrong , or maybe trying to use coffeescript breaks this somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teaspoon doesn't use node (mostly), and is primarily rails based in terms of the runner foundation. On top of the rails layer, it uses Jasmine, Mocha, or QUnit as browser test frameworks.

Trying to load a node module in to that is not really easy, or possible in some cases. If factory_girl.js can be loaded into a browser in theory you could require the file (if it's in an asset path) within your spec helper and then use it however you want.

Disclaimer: I'm the primary author of Teaspoon, but have never used factory_girl.js (but have used factory_girl the gem).

Comment: @jejacksOn ... I was poking around the files and saw the factory_girl.js file and was thinking the same thing (trying to get in included).  What I did was to copy the factory_girl.js file into spec/javascripts/support and then add #= require support/factory_girl to the spec_helper.coffee file, and I think it works.  Let me try a few things , and if it truly does work, I will mark this as the answer.  Thanks!